# If statement for string not running using equals, but contains works

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I am working on an android program that needs to identify what Wifi network a user is connected to before it implements a certain action. This is the code that I run to accomplish this:

```
     public String isConectedToPrivateNet(StringBuilder ssid) {


    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();

    ssid.replace(0, ssid.length(), wifiInfo.getSSID());
        Log.e("Data(b4 iF): ", ssid.toString());
    if(ssid.toString().equals("ACHILLES 101010")) {
        Log.e("Data (iN iF): ", ssid.toString());

    }else {
        ssid.replace(0, ssid.length(), "DIDN'T START");

    }

    return ssid.toString();

}
```

Basically this is supposed to just return the the SSID name if the if statement is true right? But it doesn't, instead it returns the "DIDN'T START". When I read my logs though, the "Data(b4 if): " shows that SSID being "ACHILLES 101010". I therefore assume that the if statement should evaluate to true, why doesn't it do so?

Here is something interesting though: If I replace the .equals(), with a .contains(), the code in the if statement block runs perfectly, and the SSID is returned. Why is this so?

*A few notes: the StringBuilder is passed as being empty here is it's declaration and initialisation

```
public StringBuilder ssid = new StringBuilder("");
```

* I also tried to use StringBuffer, and the same occurred.

Comment: Copy paste the logcat into something that shows hidden characters.

Comment: @cricket_007 I tried that man, and there are no hidden characters. I used this tool: [show hidden](http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/string-functions.php#). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem: the SSID that was returned had quotation marks in it, so it was something like this: "ACHILLES 101010", instead of just ACHILLES 101010. 
So I had to change the code to something like this:

```
if(ssid.toString().equals("\"ACHILLES 101010\"")) {
.... }
```

Thanks for all your responses, I should've posted the log to get more effective answers, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have trailing or leading spaces in your SSID string?

Try to use:

```
if (ssid.toString().trim().equals("ACHILLES 101010"))
```

trim() will remove the trailing and leading spaces.